# How to straighten AC plywood for desktop

Tags: plywood, warp, bowing

I'm building a very simple work-from-home desk, with 3/4" AC fir plywood for the top. The plywood has a concave bow on the top side.  How do I straighten this board?

Other details:

- I've already applied several coats of polyurethane to the top--perhaps this was a noob mistake to do before straightening.
- I'm planning to use sawhorses as legs, and screw a 2x4 lengthwise to the bottom of the desktop for rigidity.
- Desktop is 72"x24".
- I didn't finish the bottom. Do I need to do this for moisture reasons?

Comment: Please use the search, it works excellent here. There are at least two or three previous questions on flattening/straightening ply.

Comment: *"I didn't finish the bottom. Do I need to do this for moisture reasons?"* With ply and other manmade boards, perhaps, not for moisture reasons exactly but because of the stress induced by the drying finish. This is similar to why counter-veneering is done, a basic veneer is applied to the other side of a panel to counteract the forces from the show veneer's glue drying.

Comment: With solid-wood tabletops by the way there's no need to finish the underside, although many sources claim it's desirable or necessary **most** tabletops historically were not finished underneath, which tells us something fairly significant. Tabletops are held flat because of how they are installed, and when they bow it's not due to a weakness in the finishing regime but a flaw in the installation.

Comment: @Graphus Thanks for the tip.  Maybe I'm just searching with the wrong terms.  I just tried "how to straighten plywood," and this question was the only result.  With simply "straighten plywood" I get one additional result regarding rabbet/dado work.  What is a better search phrase?

Comment: I added the warp tag.  Click on it to find additional related questions.

Comment: The warp tag @Ashlar added will presumably find all the same relevant Q&As, but I think a search for "warp plywood" will yield results with a tighter focus. Including this one which may be most useful, https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3373/

Answer (score 0):

Plywood is difficult to straighten; it is full of glued together plys.

- You could glue/screw another warped piece with opposing curves to it.
- Screw/glue **straight** runners to the underside. 2x4's, angle iron, etc.